# Is Samsung S Health an exclusive Samsung API or is it using Google Fit?

Tags: android, google-fit, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-health

In the Samsung Galaxy S6 there is a S Health app that measures heart rate, SpO2, stress and other values. It looks like I can purchase additional apps for this. Is this S Health exclusive to Samsung? When I search online Google Fit API shows up. *I'm starting from scratch on my knowledge of this subject.*

**Background:**
I want to make an app that accesses the API's above but I'm not sure if it's an Android API, Samsung API open to developers or a closed Samsung API. How does it all fit together?

Comment: @gigawatts did u got solution

Comment: @JithishPN no answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

S Health is now available on a variety of Android devices and is no longer exclusive to Samsung devices.

To make an app that interacts with S Health, you will need an Android development environment and the Samsung Health SDK.  This can be found at: http://developer.samsung.com/health

The SDK download also includes a programming guide that can get you started.  There are also sample apps that interact with S Health here: http://developer.samsung.com/sample-app/list.do

Comment: Just in case anyone comes here looking for answers about Samsung Health, their API is now closed and it requires an application process where you must have a large number of downloads to be approved.